# sending messages to properties in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I dont understand this line of code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"hello";
```

to my understanding this is the equivalent to:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:@"Hello"];
```

textLabel is a getter method from UILabelViewCell class, and setText is a setter method from UILabel class, right?? UITableViewCell returns (UILabel *) variable then we send this variable a method called setText?? I dont understand how we can send a method to a variable!
please explain.
thank you in advance

Comment: This seems to lack a basic understanding, may I recommend going all the way back to the beginning and start learning programming languages again.

Comment: Maybe you mark the answer which helped you most, so the post will be closed.

Comment: best to understand the very basics of objective c follow [http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[cell textLabel]` returns the label of the cell. It(label) is an object.

That object has one property called `text`. So either you can set the property using `.` dot notation or by using setter `setText:`.

Answer (score 2):

textLabel here is also an object, and setText is a method of that object.

Comment: Thnks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Anoop Vaidya told you, the first part, `[self textLabel]` is an object. If you define a property for your object like this in the header file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *string;
```

the `getter` and `setter` will also be generated. Thats why you can access the `properties` by dot notation as well as `setMyVariable`. Go and try to implement the getter and setter of your property and xCode will show you immediately the right method by autocompletion. For example for the string above you have the setter.

```
- (void)setString:(NSString *)string
```